# Laravel: How to properly rewrite an authentification route in an MVC?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8

I have to setup my authentication for my reservations system in Laravel.

The basic routing methods by Laravel and a lot of tutorials is by writing the function for the route inside the web.php like this **Laraval example**:

```
Route::get('/flights', function () {
    // Only authenticated users may access this route...
})->middleware('auth');
```

However, I was told this isn't the best way to set up routing and that I should use a controller to manage routes.
But that means I have to setup authentification methods inside the controller and to be honest, I don't have the vision to do this..
I thought I could do it like this (**My Code**)

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Providers\RouteServiceProvider;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

class PagesController extends Controller
{
    public function home() {
        return view('home');
    }

    public function reservations() {
        return view('reservations')
        ->middleware(['auth']);
    }

    public function newreservations() {
        return view('reservations_new');
    }

 }
```

combined with this web.php setup:

```
Route::get('/reservations.html', [PagesController::class, 'reservations']);

Route::get('/reservations.html/login', [AuthenticatedSessionController::class, 'create']);

Route::post('/reservations.html/login', [AuthenticatedSessionController::class, 'store']);

Route::get('/reservations_new.html', [PagesController::class, 'newReservations']);
```

but then I got the error:
*Method Illuminate\View\View::middleware does not exist.*

So any tips/tricks/methods to do it the right way?

Answer (score 1):

There is no right or wrong way as long as you follow the same principal.

I personally do this:

```
Route::middleware('auth')->group(function () {
    // Authenticated routes
});
```

you can check [this extended discussion](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/middleware-in-controller-or-on-route)

also if you want to use middlewares in controller, [this is the right way](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/controllers#controller-middleware)

```
class UserController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Instantiate a new controller instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('auth');
        $this->middleware('log')->only('index');
        $this->middleware('subscribed')->except('store');
    }
}
```

Comment: I'll give it a try!. Thanks in advance

Comment: So the error is gone, but I got redirected to the reservation view.
So the login isn't showing up. 
What should I do with my routes?

Comment: @Stef-Verniers you cant see login page if you are already authenticated, check Authenticate middleware to change auth logic for already logged in users

Comment: In the documentation was the solution to setup my routes. So thank you for the reference!!

Comment: I will edit your comment to require the desired solution